# -Batch- Make characters from word

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm working on huge batch file and i need to, when user will write Hello for example to:

```
set input =
set /p input=Type hello here:
```

I need to make **H e l l o** from it..
and save it to txt

```
%character_input% >hash.txt
```

Can you help me please? thanks..

Comment: So... why do you have to make individual characters from what they typed? Why not just write what they typed directly into the file? It seems like you're not asking for what you really want.

Comment: @SpikeX - no, I need to make characters from that.. my plan is.. replace each character with other character.. I dont know if there is any other option how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch file outputs every character on separate line by essentially processing the variable character by character. This should get you started. :)

```
@echo off

REM Get the input any way you want. Mine is hard-coded.
set input=Hello world

REM Add a terminator to prevent the loop stopping on a space
set input=%input%x

:loop

REM Extract the first character
set i=%input:~0,1%

REM Remove the first character from the input
set input=%input:~1%

REM Output the single character
echo.%i%

REM If the terminator is all that's left, terminate
if "%input%"=="x" goto done
goto :loop

:done
```

Comment: Fun question! I thought `FOR /f` would have a feature for it, but apparently it doesn't.